# Exactly _what_ is different about being a graduate student vs. undergraduate? (Think: day-to-day)

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

I'm entering the last year of my undergraduate. In all honesty, I'm getting tired of it; I want to move on to something new.

For a long time, I thought a master's degree was New Game Plus (that is, just a more demanding version of a bachelor's). Don't get me wrong; I've had little to no trouble with my undergrad, but you couldn't get me to do another one ever again!

Well, here's the conundrum: everyone tells me I *have* to do a master's, and that it's not what I think it is.

Well, what is it?

What are the real differences between an undergraduate program and a graduate program? For example, what are the differences in your day-to-day dealings? In what way are yours and the professors' motivations different?

--

For bonus points: if you personally chose to do a master's, or to avoid one, why did you make this decision?

Comment: This can vary but pretty much: one you take classes, the other you do research. Completely different things.

Comment: What does the day-to-day work of a researcher look like? Have you done this before? And don't most master's students actually take classes anyway?

Comment: Not all master's students do research. I'm in a MS program and I have no more research than I did in my undergrad. Personally, I chose to do a Masters because I wanted the credentials and it was something on my bucket list.

Comment: What country is this?  Typical day-to-day life for students varies rather widely around the world.

Comment: As @NateEldredge commented it depends a lot on the country. For instance, in my country, industries tend not to hire people who just have a Bachelor's. Thus, for your bonus point, this could be a good reason for many students to enroll in a Master's program.

Comment: In my country Masters's is normal classes. Bachelor is perceived as almost incomplete uni education. When I studied it it was just 5 years MS straight from the high school. You are expected to do the equivalent MS or MEng and it is not too different from Bc, except of a nit more time for the thesis (which is not necessarily scientific, only at some unis).

Comment: I did my BSc/MSc in Spain. The MSc life was just "more of the same". Surely the topics were more advanced, but also everyone brain had more understanding.  In terms of effort and life I noticed no difference. I live in the UK now, and it doesn't feel like the same thing. As a Phd postgraduate, the life is very different though. It is like a job (in the UK).

Comment: Over here masters students almost never do research so it's the same style just more advanced concepts and courses, and you can't skip doing a masters and hop right on a PhD either.

Comment: A word on terminology: “graduate student” in Europe means PhD student, not masters student. This exemplifies the country-by-country differences you should expect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(I am in linguistics and my master's degree was heavily research-based.)

I remember an undergrad professor of mine cautioning her class as follows: "Being a graduate student is *very* different from being an undergraduate student." Three months into my MA, I found myself thinking, 'no it isn't', but *six* months into my MA, I thought, '...okay, yeah, it totally is'. The skills that the degree aims to impart are quite different: going to classes starts out feeling similar, but over the course of any graduate degree it should evolve from 'building knowledge base' to 'reading the literature critically and coming up with new ideas'.

To me the biggest difference, psychologically speaking, aside from the *big* step up into the unknown (= major original research) was in terms of project scope. As an undergrad, I could run myself out of homework for the day, or the weekend, and then relax, because I'd dealt with everything I needed to do. Beyond the undergraduate level, that kind of stops happening. A grad-student in any program with a research component always has that work at least in the background, and projects are *enormous* in comparison to most undergrad coursework. You *can't* run yourself out of work for the day, or for the weekend. The research is ongoing; there's always more to be done. It's a marathon rather than a bunch of little sprints. You have to keep coming back to a thesis and picking up where you left off. At the graduate level you have to develop have a sense of how to work on something a little at a time. And how to put it away and to (try and) do something fun once in a while.

Comment: I wanted to add to the really nice aspect of 'never running out of work' pointed out by @trikeprof. I often think of being a grad student as being a one-person company - your publications are your product, you are the CEO. And so the onus is entirely on you to constantly produce new results, and up your brand (especially if you want to get into academia). If there's any 'extra' time, you can always use it to do something that'll make you a stronger researcher. So  you never stop :-)

Answer (score 11):

first, it's hard to group all grad programs singularly.  many programs have three sort of "classifications" of graduate students based on the degree they are seeking:  M.S. non-thesis, M.S. thesis, and Ph.D.  each of these classifications will have a different "day-to-day" and purpose.

M.S. non-thesis option is not terribly different from undergrad.  you're taking classes, and that's about it.  hours spent per week will be governed by the amount of homework/assignments you have in class.  hence, hours spent per week will be similar, maybe slightly more intensive, than undergrad.  end game for most M.S. non-thesis students is to work in industry doing similar job functions as a B.S., but at a slightly higher salary.

M.S. thesis option will involve 1-2 courses/semester, plus research directed/guided by your advisor.  the research will require a significant time investment, and a lot more creative, independent thinking than courses.  that is, courses are VERY guided since there's a clear set of expectations such as homework sets.  research, on the other hand, requires you to think critically about what you're doing, analyze your results, interpret enough that you can explain those results or devise next steps to help you explain unexpected results, etc.  career path for many M.S. thesis students is sometimes industry, sometimes a research lab-type setting.

Ph.D. involves 1-2 courses/semester for just 2-3 years, plus a significant amount of unique, independent, first-of-a-kind research.  typically the research will be guided by your advisor for the first couple years, then they'll expect that you eventually become self-guided.  at the end of the Ph.D. you should be the world's expert on that topic.  but, this doesn't come without a cost -- many successful Ph.D. students log well more than 40 hours/week on their research alone (course work is done on top of that).  the biggest misunderstanding students have is assuming that coursework is important in the Ph.D., and spending too much time trying to get "A's" in courses.  the research is extremely crucial, and should be the focal point for the student from the get-go.  courses are there to help you learn topics that will inform your research.  career paths for most Ph.D. graduates is independent research in academic, lab, or industry settings.

Comment: It would be helpful to quality this answer with a country. Much of what you specify about the different degrees is simply not correct everywhere. For instance, depending on where you go for a PhD, it is totally possible there are no courses at all. Likewise, depending on the place, a Master thesis can be roughly the same (albeit more advanced and elaborate in content) as a Bachelor thesis.

Comment: Good point -- I am answering for USA.